# Ubuntu touch availability on TF101

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to ask if there is any plan or indicative timeline if an installation would be made available for Asus Transformer TF101 device.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2168473

this is still a pre-alapha build, so it will be extremely unstable and a lot of the features are still not working, so i would wait until it has at least reached a a stage where most of the features are working.
PLEASE TRY AT YOUR OWN RISK!!!

All credit goes to raymanfx, Canonical, and jholtom.